# Structre of R in QR factorization for a matrix that its odd columns are orthogonal to its even columns

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$ be a full rank matrix with the property that columns $1 ,3 , 5 , 7 , ...\quad$ are orthogonal to columns $2 ,4 , 6 , 8, ...$. In a reduced $QR$ factorization $A=\hat{Q}\hat{R}$, what special structure does $\hat{R}$ possess?

Solving this manually leads to following matrix.
 $$R=
\begin{bmatrix} x_{1}&0&y_{1}&0&&&&...\\0&x_{2}&0&y_{2}&0&&&...\\0&0&x_{3}&0&y_{3}&&&...\\0&0&0&x_{4}&0&&&y_{4}\\ &&&...&&&&0\\0&...&&&&&&x_{5}\end{bmatrix} $$
I don't know how to prove this formally.
Does any one have an insight on this?

Thanks.

=====

I added the steps I have done to solve the problem manually:

I’ve tried the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization as follow:

$ q_n = \frac{a_n- \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}r_{in}q_{i}}{r_{nn}}$

$ r_{ij} = q_i^{*}a_{j} \quad \quad i \neq j $

$ |r_{jj} |=  || a_{jj} - \sum_{i=1}^{j-1} q_{i}r_{ij} ||_{2}\quad \quad i = j $

$q_{1} = \frac{a_{1}}{||a_{11}||} \quad q_{2} = \frac{a_{2}}{||a_{22}||}\quad q_{3} = \frac{a_{3}-\frac{(a_{1}.a_{3})a_{1}}{||a_{1}||^{2}}}{|| a_{3}-\frac{(a_{1}.a_{3})a_{1}}{||a_{1}||^{2}}||} $

$r_{11} = ||a_1||\quad$
$r_{22} = ||a_2||\quad$
$r_{12}=0 \quad ....$

$q_{1}$ is a linear combination of $a_{1}$

$q_{2}$ is a linear combination of $a_{2}$

$q_{3}$ is a linear combination of $a_{1},a_{3} $

$q_{4}$ is a linear combination of $a_{2},a_{4} $

...

$$R=
\begin{bmatrix}
||a_{1}|| & 0 & \frac{a_1.a_3}{||a_{1}||} & 0 &... \\
0 & ||a_{2}||& 0 & val\neq0 &0 & ...\\ 0&0&||a_{3}-\frac{a_{1}.a_{3}}{||a_{1}||^{2}}{a_{1}||} & ...\\ .\\.\\.\end{bmatrix} $$

In matrix $R$:

If $i = j$: $r_{ij}\neq0$

If $i > j$ :$r_{ij}=0$

If $i<j$ &  both $i,j$ are either odd  or even then $r_{ij}\neq0$

Comment: How did you solve it manually?

Comment: @msm I added the details below my post.